# simulate.Arima function from the forecast package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am using the package forecast for seasonal times series simulations and I have two questions :

1) I don't exactly get the meaning and the utility of the "future" option. It is set to TRUE by default, and I think it should be so if I want to predict future values of the series, but I don't understand what is the use of a simulation with future=FALSE.

2) The simulate.Arima function is basically an improvement for the traditionnal arima.sim one. However with arima.sim, it is possible to provide some user-defined innovations processes to the function using the innov argument while it is not possible to do so with simulate.Arima. Did I miss something ? If not, and if Mr Hyndman reads this post, could it be possible to add such an option in a future release ? For the moment, I think I'll get the source code and try to modify the code by myself.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: @RobHyndman frequently reads CrossValidated, apparently less so StackExchange. If you don't get an answer here, you could go to his website at http://robjhyndman.com/ and send him a quick email message.

Answer (score 6):

1. According to the help file, `future` means "Produce sample paths
   that are future to and conditional on the data in object.". So if
   `future=TRUE`, the simulated observations are conditional on the
   historical observations. In other words, they are possible future
   sample paths of the time series. But if `future=FALSE`, the
   historical data are ignored, and the simulations are possible
   realizations of the time series model that are not connected to the
   original data.
2. I will add the suggestion of allowing user-specified innovations to
   the list of feature requests at
   https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues?state=open. In the meantime, it is a very easy modification. Just find the call to `rnorm` and replace it.

Answer (score 4):

It is useful to set the `future` option to `FALSE` when you want to examine the fit of the model to your data. For example, in the plot below, the model fit is in red while the actual data is in black.

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(USAccDeaths)
plot(simulate(fit,future=FALSE),col='red')
lines(c(USAccDeaths))
```

[image]

Even more interesting would be to get the difference between the two:

```
plot(simulate(fit,future=FALSE)-c(USAccDeaths))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that the difference between two realizations from the same model tells you anything useful.